# Unable to scroll the web page

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, devise

I am developing a website using Ruby on Rails. I am facing an issue where I am unable to scroll the webpage vertically. The scroll bar does appear but it doesn't scroll down. If I resize my webpage, only the contents which fit in the page are displayed. I am using devise authentication for signup/login/logout. If I comment out the following devise code, scroll does work (for home page). Can someone please help me.

In application.html,

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
 <ul class="navbar-text pull-right">
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
   <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <%= current_user.email %><b class="caret"></b></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">

         <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'Edit profile', edit_user_registration_path %></li>

         <li class="divider"></li>
         <li><%= link_to 'My Profile', users_show_path %></li>

         <li class="divider"></li>
         <li><%=link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete%></li>

    </ul>

 </li>
 </ul>
   <% else %>
  <ul class="navbar-text pull-right">
  <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path, :class => 'navbar-link'  %> |
  <%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path, :class => 'navbar-link'  %>
</ul>-->
<%end %>



<div class="ContentContainer">
<%= yield %>
</div><!--end of Content container div-->

</body>
</html>

In custom.css,

.ContentContainer
{
  position: relative;
  margin: 200px 50px;
  min-height: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
html
{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
body { 
   width: 1000px;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: please attach your css. Because it seems like css issue.

Comment: Can u remove class  nav bar fixed top and try once. From the name of the class. It says it is fixing the top of screen. Just a guess until you post your css

Comment: Hi Hemali, Thank you so much for pointing out that.. I came to know that I didn't close the <div class nav bar fixed top>  and hence I could not scroll down.. Thanks a lot for your help. Issue got solved :-)